# I tried everything but I can't seem to draw something in jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe

i am new to java and i need help to get this working. I tried paintComponent, super, and much more. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I am just trying to make a simple circle. I first tried with different classes but I now came back to only one.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JPanel{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;

    public Main() {
        
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel();
        
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("shotergame");
        
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 600));
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.drawOval(100, 100, 50, 50);
        g2d.fillOval(100, 100, 50, 50);
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        new Main();

    }
    
    

}
```

Comment: You don't add an instance of your `Main()` class (which contains the painting code) to the frame. Instead you add a regular JPanel which has no custom painting. However, this is NOT the proper solution. Your `Main()` class should NOT extend JPanel, it is just a class to build the frame and add components to the frame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for  examples that will show you how to better structure your code so you don't make this mistake.

Comment: *I tried paintComponent, super...* - which is the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

`Main` is the `JPanel` to add to the `JFrame`.
The `panel` instance doesn't do anything, you should get rid of it and use `this` instance in the constructor instead.

```java
public class Main extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JFrame frame;

    public Main() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(this); // Add "this" instance
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("shotergame");
        
        // Set preferred size to "this" instance
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 600));
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    (...)
}
```

Comment: (1-) this may fix the problem but it is NOT the solution. A JPanel class should NOT create the frame itself. The JPanel class should only contain the code directly related to the painting of the panel itself. If should not know or care what frame or dialog or other panel it may eventually be added to. Read the tutorial link I provided in the comments to the question for better structured code.

Comment: @camickr This code snippet works and fixes the problem. If your comments are about best practices and code optimization, they would probably be more helpful on questions about best practices and code optimization, like on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: My comment was intended to let the OP (and you) know that this answer could be improved, and really was unnecessary. since it added nothing new. My original comment gave the solution hours before this answer was posted. A good answer will include comments about issues with the code even when not directly related to the problem in the hope of helping the OP write better code and reduce future problems.

Comment: @camickr Thank you for your honesty. I agree, of course, you did provide a solution. Maybe it was a little technical or something, but I thought a detailed explanation and a piece of code might be helpful. All the informations you would expect to see in a good answer are already there, in your first comments.